# How to automatically continue ordered list numbering in table rows

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to find a (preferably vanilla) JavaScript solution that will allow me to automatically continue an ordered list in multiple table rows. I want to accomplish the same thing as hard coding  but without having to hard code anything. This is the end result I'm after:

```css
table {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

td {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ol>
        <li>Do this</li>
        <li>Then do this</li>
        <li>After that, do this</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td>Image goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ol start="4">
        <li>Then do this</li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td>Image goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ol start="5">
        <li>Then do that</li>
        <li>And then do this</li>
    </td>
    <td>Image goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is for a series of articles with step-by-step instructions. The articles will be written by non-coders, which is why I don't want them to have to hard code anything. Also, if any steps are added or subtracted in the future, I don't want them to have to go in to the code to reorder all the steps by hand.

I'm using a table to keep images aligned with their associated steps because that's what the article writers are familiar with, and because I'm able to convince myself that the steps and their associated images are data, and therefore appropriate to display in a table, rather than trying to tackle this from a CSS layout perspective, which would be even harder for my non-coding article writers. :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're using tables for presentation. Don't. This is exactly what flex-box was introduced for, and if column widths depend on other content below then you need CSS grids. But definitely not tables :)

Comment: @BrandonHill While using tables for layout isn't ideal, this problem would still apply to a flex/grid based layout.

Comment: I can appreciate that. Normally, I would never use a table for this. The problem with using CSS in this case is that it requires coding and for the article writers to place the content in the correct divs. These articles will be in a ticketing system knowledge base, and my writers have to work in a WYSIWYG text editor.

Comment: So, will every list item in this table be sequential? Or does it need to allow for multiple lists?

Comment: There will be only one list in an article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS, you can keep track of the element number using a `counter()`.

If you target the `table li` you can insert a pseudo-element just as described on this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```css
table { counter-reset: li; }
table li::before {
    counter-increment: li;
    content: counter(li) ". ";
}
ol { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <ol><li>first</li><li>second</li></ol>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <ol><li>third</li><li>fourth</li></ol>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just select all the ols and keep track of how many children.

```js
const ols = document.querySelectorAll(".myTable ol");
let cnt = 1;
ols.forEach(ol => {
  ol.setAttribute("start", cnt);
  cnt += ol.querySelectorAll("li").length;
});
```

```html
<div class="myTable">
  <ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>6</li>
  </ol>
  <ol>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Funny I am getting downvoted when they asked for a "hoping to find a (preferably vanilla) JavaScript solution " so that is what this was.